# "R_WERKS" is not type-compatible with formal parameter "ia_werks"

Tags: abap

I am getting crazy with that compile error

> "R_WERKS" is not type-compatible with formal parameter "ia_werks"

I know that selection-options are generating a header line, that's why I have a call like that:

```
DATA: object TYPE REF TO zcl_class, 
      r_werks TYPE RANGE OF eine-werks.

r_werks[] = s_werks[].

CALL METHOD zcl_class=>set_attribute
   CHNANGING
       ia_werks = r_werks.
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: What exactly is the type of the `ia_werks`?

Comment: How the SELECT-OPTION is defined? How is the ia-werks defined? A possible pitfall is that WERKS is a structure in the repository (contains a single field also called WERKS), but the data elements is WERKS_D

Comment: `A possible pitfall is that WERKS is a structure in the repository (contains a single field also called WERKS), but the data elements is WERKS_D ` yeah, some dark mind invented this coward pitfall, hahaha

Comment: IA_WERKS is eine-werks, s_werks is also eine-werks, thats why i am so lost...

Comment: Please post a complete [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that we can reproduce and understand the problem, so that to give an adequate answer.

Comment: @Patrick Did you solve your issue? If yes, what was the problem, and could you tell us how you solved it? Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

`IA_WERKS` is `TYPE EINE-WERKS` and `r_werks TYPE RANGE OF eine-werks` so the error makes sense.

You also need to make `IA_WERKS type RANGE`:

1. go to class `zcl_class` and click on 'Types' tab
2. create a type `types TY_RANGE TYPE RANGE OF eine-WERKS.` (to do that click on 'Direct Type Entry'):

[image]

Go back to `IA_WERKS` and set it `TYPE TY_RANGE.`

It should work now.